# Order of events in primeng's multiselect component

Tags: angular, primeng

I've been having problems with using multiselect component from primeng library in Angular. Everything seemed to be working fine until i noticed some weird problem with events order (i guess). 
Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7dfgq

The "interesting" thing happens here:

```
<p-multiSelect #select="ngModel" required [options]="options"  [(ngModel)]="selected"  [showHeader]=false></p-multiSelect>

<div *ngIf="select.invalid && select.touched"> Validation error </div>
```

So as you may assume I'm trying to show some message when there are no values selected (control is in invalid and touched state). Now, when you first time hit the page, that control has `untouched` and `invalid` statuses and therefore message isn't shown (so far so good). However when you now click on some option the message 'blinks' which is not the desired behaviour (it shouldn't pop up at all in that state). From what i understand (based on primeng code on github - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts) `onInputBlur` method is called before `onOptionClick` and it casuses control to change its state to `touched` before changing select value (and making it valid).

So now the question, any ideas how can i fix this 'blinking'? I guess extending the component would be the only option, but even then... how can i change the order of events? (so that `onOptionClick` is trigger sooner than `onInputBlur`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onPanelHide` event indicates that the [multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) element has been "touched" and the [NgModel.dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#dirty) flag indicates that the user has made selection changes. You can combine the two in the validation condition:

```
<p-multiSelect #select="ngModel" required [options]="options" 
  [(ngModel)]="selected" [showHeader]=false 
  (onPanelHide)="panelClosed = true"></p-multiSelect>

<div *ngIf="select.invalid && (select.dirty || panelClosed)"> Validation error </div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amdsbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Hmm... yeah but that won't work (message not shown) if user opens multiselect and closes it without selecting anything. Is there any way to stick with touched and invalid flags and fix the blinking?

Comment: I updated the answer. The validation message is shown if the multiselect has been touched and no item is selected, while avoiding the "blinking problem" on the first selection.